# Google Sheets Cell Reference

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Form linked to a Google Sheet with two files. One file is the responses that are pushed from the form and the other sheet I am using to combine all of the answers into one cell to send an email to the user. I am using this formula to pull in the user email: ='Form Responses 1'!B2

The issue I am having is the form inserts a new cell with each response, so the response will go into the B2 cell but the formula will change to ='Form Responses 1'!B3 when this happens. How do I make B2 the absolute reference even if a new row is inserted?

Answer (score 2):

Use INDIRECT

Example

```
=INDIRECT("Form Responses 1!B2")
```