# Google Sheets Cell Reference +1

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am wanting to enter a bunch of cell references that are affected by a change in only one of them. On one sheet tab, I have a list of dates in column C, and dollar figures in both D and E. In another sheet tab, I want to have a cell that reflects the first date on the original tab. Then in another 2 cells, the dollar figures related to that date. But I want to be able to just change the cell referencing the date to the next date and have the dollar figures do the same as per the date cell.
Kind of like this:

This cell is referencing the date cell (`=Sheet1!C3`)
Then for the dollar cells (`=Sheet1!(C+1)3`) - so that the reference ends up being for cell D3.

I also want to be able to do that for the row (`=Sheet1C(3+1)`) - so it is actually meaning C4.

I hope that makes sense!

Comment: Use INDIRECT function.

Comment: Related (the same answer): [Google Sheets Cell Reference](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/114136/88163),  [Google Sheets, formula, reference to variable sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/117822/88163)

Answer (score 0):

> (`=Sheet1!(C+1)3`) - so that the reference ends up being for cell D3

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&ADDRESS(3, 3+ROW(A1), 4))
```

> (`=Sheet1C(3+1)`) - so it is actually meaning C4

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&ADDRESS(3+COLUMN(A1), 3, 4))
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I had do to a little shuffling around to get it work how I wanted it to but got the result I wanted, so thanks!

Comment: @Josh https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers