# How do I increase google sheets cell number by adding 20 in a formular

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to use "+" or "- " in referencing a cell eg

=i(10+23) = i33 .

So that I don't have to increment the cell reference manually .

Any help would be great ?

Comment: Related: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/130710/88163

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`INDEX` function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en), combined with `ROW()` and `COLUMN()`. Here are two simple examples:

- Left: `=INDEX(A:A, 5)` returns the contents of the fifth cell in column A.
- Right: `=INDEX(A:A, ROW()+5)` returns the contents of the cell five rows down in column A. All cells in italic use the same formula.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score -2):

I'm not entirely following the request without a test sheet, but it sounds like you're just trying to add or subtract 20 from a value depending on if you input a "+" or a "-".

If that's the case, you can use the two columns next to your data. In the first, you could manually input your "+" or "-".  In the column next to it, you can have an if statement saying

"If(b2="+",a2+20,if(b2="-",a2-20),"")

By doing this and dragging the formula down, each cell will move based off of your plus or minus.

If this doesn't answer your question, could you please share a test sheet?